postscript: how to make two nested for loops
Want to print a raster of circles in a rectangular frame. Found example of one loop, worked fine. Added a second loop inside, no good; I only get a single column of circles. Suggestions welcome!
% raster and mms defined higher up

newpath 0 0 raster 24 mul raster 16 mul rectstroke

/x 0 def  /y 0 def
{
 x 15 gt { exit } if
 { y 23 gt { exit } if
    x 0.5 add raster mul 
    y 0.5 add raster mul
    2.5 mms 0 359 arc stroke
   /y y 1 add def
 } loop
 /x x 1 add def
} loop


you would need to reset x to 0 when you exit the inner y loop. A more elegant solution probably would not use x and y at all but simply put the current values on the stack

Been there, tried that :) Apparently above my capacities. Would you have an example to share?

Below answer works like a charm, and helped my understanding much. Herzlich Dank!

Adans accepting the answer is also accepted as thanks!! ;-)

untested:
0 % start of x loop on stack
{
  dup 15 gt { pop exit } if % exit and remove x value
  0 % start of y loop on stack
  {
    dup 23 gt { pop exit } if % exit and remove y value
    %% optional: 2 copy == == will print current y and x value
    1 index 0.5 add raster mul % take x value and calculate
    1 index 0.5 add raster mul % take y value and calculate
    2.5 mms 0 359 arc stroke 
    1 add % replace y value on stack with increased one
  } loop
  1 add % replace x value on stack with increased one
} loop


Suggest using the Postscript 'for' operator for this:
0 1 15{
    /x exch def
    0 1 23{
        /y exch def
        x 0.5 add raster mul 
        y 0.5 add raster mul
        2.5 mms 0 359 arc stroke
    }for % y loop
}for % x loop

